# jquery добавить запись в таблицу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно ссылка: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6LLag8g/1/)

```js
$("#sends-table-body").append("<tr><tb>76561198313642312</tb><tb>20</tb><tb>2017-12-02 04:12:57</tb></tr>));
```

```css
   table.responsive-table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        display: block;
        position: relative
    }
    table.responsive-table td:empty:before {
        content: '\00a0'
    }
    table.responsive-table td,
    table.responsive-table th {
        margin: 0;
        vertical-align: top
    }
    table.responsive-table th {
        text-align: left
    }
    table.responsive-table thead {
        display: block;
        float: left
    }
    table.responsive-table thead tr {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 10px 0 0
    }
    table.responsive-table thead tr th::before {
        content: "\00a0"
    }
    table.responsive-table tbody {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: nowrap
    }
    table.responsive-table tbody tr {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top
    }
    table.responsive-table th {
        display: block;
        text-align: right
    }
    table.responsive-table td {
        display: block;
        min-height: 1.25em;
        text-align: left
    }
    table.responsive-table tr {
        padding: 0 10px
    }
    table.responsive-table thead {
        border: 0;
        border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0
    }
    table.responsive-table.bordered th {
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-left: 0
    }
    table.responsive-table.bordered td {
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        border-bottom: 0
    }
    table.responsive-table.bordered tr {
        border: 0
    }
    table.responsive-table.bordered tbody tr {
        border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sends-table" class="responsive-table">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th data-lang="account_sends_user">Пользователь</th>
                           <th data-lang="account_sends_value">Стоимость</th>
                           <th data-lang="account_sends_date">Дата</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody id="sends-table-body"><tr></tr></tbody>
                  </table>
```

Почему данный код не работает, я уже всю голову сломал

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что SO имеет свой собственный инструмент для создания примерa, воспроизводящего проблему, которую пытается решить автор. Не говоря уже о том, что "я голову сломал" мне ничего не говорит.

Comment: Зайти и посмотреть тебе религия запрещает ? Не умею я пользоваться встроенным инструментом

Comment: плохо ломали, кавычки в конце нет, скобка лишняя, и `tb` вместо `td`

Comment: @LorDo заработав 300 очков репутации, можно было научиться хотя бы ссылки нормально вставлять

Comment: формально, код работает. если бы вы ткнули в инструменты разработчика браузера и в инспекторе посмотрели dom, то tr добавляется вполне

Comment: @LorDo `Не умею я пользоваться встроенным инструментом` - придется учиться. Ведь данный ресурс не консультация конкретно вас, а база знания для всех

Comment: Все я понял в чем проблема, 12 часов работаю без перерыва, видимо мозг отключается, я написал tb а не td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

замените на:

```
$("#sends-table-body").append("<tr><td>76561198313642312</td><td>20</td><td>2017-12-02 04:12:57</td></tr>");
```

во первых заменить тег tb на td, во вторых кавычку забыли закрыть.